# How to rectify my own image to the cameras of the KITTI dataset using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, camera, computer-vision, stereoscopy, kitti

Based on the documentation of [stereo-rectify](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereorectify) from OpenCV, one can rectify an image based on two camera matrices, their distortion coefficients, and a rotation-translation from one camera to another.

I would like to rectify an image I took using my own camera to the stereo setup from the [KITTI dataset](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/raw_data.php). From their calibration files, I know the camera matrix and size of images before rectification of all the cameras.  All their data is calibrated to their ***camera_0***.

From this [PNG](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/setup.php), I know the position of each of their cameras relative to the front wheels of the car and relative to ground.

I can also do a monocular calibration on my camera and get a camera matrix and distortion coefficients.

I am having trouble coming up with the rotation and translation matrix/vector between the coordinate systems of the first and the second cameras, i.e. from their camera to mine or vice-versa.

I positioned my camera on top of my car at almost exactly the same height and almost exactly the same distance from the center of the front wheels, as shown in the [PNG](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/setup.php).

However now I am at a loss as to how I can create the joint rotation-translation matrix. In a normal stereo-calibrate, these are returned by the [setereoCalibrate](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereocalibrate) function.

I looked at some references about [coordinate transformation](https://www.continuummechanics.org/coordxforms.html) but I don't have sufficient practice in them to figure it out on my own.

Any suggestions or references are appreciated!